# Magento 2 Overriding template is not working

Tags: magento2, template, theme

I have created a new theme and i'm trying to override a template (same example as Magento Developer guide

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-sample.html)

so i just added this file

> magento2/app/design/frontend/Plata/platatheme/Magento_Checkout/web/templates/minicart/content.html

and changed something as they suggest. Then i reloaded and nothing changed, it always load the old version.

I removed all files from **pub/static**, run magento `setup:static-content:deploy` and flushed both magento and browser cache.

I checked in

> pub/static/frontend/Plata/platatheme/en_US/Magento_Checkout/templates/minicart/content.html

and there is my version of the file.

Should i run some more commands from the terminal?

Comment: have you changed theme from content->design-> configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your File Path Mismatch

Your File path

> magento2/app/design/frontend/Plata/platatheme/Magento_Checkout/web/**templates**/minicart/content.html

Change Like:

> magento2/app/design/frontend/Plata/platatheme/Magento_Checkout/web/**template**/minicart/content.html

After Change this Clear **cache**, and **generate static content** then check it.

Reference: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-sample.html

Comment: So it's "templates" inside their module and template in my custom theme, Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

You have wrong file path

> magento2/app/design/frontend/Plata/platatheme/Magento_Checkout/web/**templates**/minicart/content.html

Should be

> magento2/app/design/frontend/Plata/platatheme/Magento_Checkout/web/template/minicart/content.html

Remove pub/static/*

Run below command

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

php bin magento cache:clean
```

Delete you browser cache, you can get your changes now.